# Order status not show in magento Orders List page

Tags: magento2

In Orders page not showing order status but i got orders using API , in this orders have order status, but it not display in Magento

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check this. It may help you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244993/order-status-not-changed-in-the-sales-order-grid-magento-2

Comment: Please check this. It may help you
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244993/order-status-not-changed-in-the-sales-order-grid-magento-2